# Why can't I use any of the functionality of my installed NuGet packages, when installed trough NuGet package manager?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nuget-package

I'm new to ASP.net programming (not programming in general) and are following a course online.

I have a big problem, that seems to be in Visual Studio, probably with the NuGet package manager.

The problem resides in, that I install the packages, but I can't use them.

Here is an example.

I have installed the Entity framework in my class library:

[image: Solution Explore picture]

And my CSPROJ also looks ok to me:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\OdeToFood.core\OdeToFood.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
        
</Project>
```

When I run the `dotnet ef` command in the project, I get:

```
PS H:\Pluralsight\asp.net core\OdeToFood\OdeToFood\OdeToFood.Data> dotnet ef
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

Also, an error in the Package Manager Console.

And if I run `dotnet -h ef` it doesn't show under SDK, but it did in the course video I'm following.

I have:

- The newest version of VS
- Rebuild the solution and the class library
- Restarted VS
- The latest stable version of the packages

It was also a problem when I did it with Font Awesome, but I installed that as a client-side library with Libman instead, because I didn't want to fight with it anymore at that time. But, I really want my package manager to work.

Comment: https://github.com/OdeToCode/OdeToFood#clip-4-using-the-entity-framework-tools: _"Starting in 3.0, the dotnet ef command-line tool is no longer included in the .NET Core SDK. Before you can execute EF Core migration or scaffolding commands, you’ll have to install this package as either a global or local tool. To install the latest version as a global tool, use the following command:

`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`"_.

Comment: So it looks like you're following a course made 2 years ago, in which time about everything about .NET Core changed.